# Add new item to auto filter operator on xtragrid column

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

How can I modify the default filter operator on DevExpress.Xtragrid.gridcontrol and add a new value there with what is already there.

Simple I want to add "Greater than > 0" to a numeric value column, keeping what it is already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link, it helps. 
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument2567

```
gridView1.ActiveFilterString = "[YOURCOLUMN] > 0";
```

Answer (score 1):

To add yet another condition please combine it with 'AND':

```
gridView1.ActiveFilterString = gridView1.ActiveFilterString + " AND [ColumnName] > 0";
```

**Update:**
You can use the [ColumnView.MRUFilters](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_MRUFilterstopic) property to customize the recently used filters collection if necessary. Elements in the collection are represented by [ViewFilter](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseViewFiltertopic) objects.